# In Monogame/XNA, Is there an event that is triggered when the GraphicsDevice resolution is changed?

Tags: c#, events, xna, monogame

I can see GraohicsDevice.DeviceReset, but is that called when the resolution changes?

EDIT: No, it isn't.  What is?

Comment: If you change the resolution, you have to call `graphics.applyChanges()`

Comment: Okay, but is there an event triggered that I can rely on to tell my stuff that the resolution has changed?

Answer (score 2):

GraphicsDeviceManager.DeviceReset

Is the event you are looking for.

It can be attached to from your game class during initialize.